# Multi-Threading not working correctly

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

**Edit**
This post pertains to a homework assignment I have for school that dictates I rely on swing to display my threads and boolean flags for blocking.

My application creates a bunch of "job" objects that each contain a thread. Each job belongs to a creature. A creature can possess multiple jobs but can only perform 1 of them at any given moment.

My thread utilizes 2 boolean flags to tell whether or not it should be running called "killFlag" and "goFlag". It designates the creature it belongs to as "target". And each target has a boolean "isWorking" to denote whether or not it is busy with another job.

This is the thread each job should run:

```
public void run() {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long startTime = time;
    long stopTime = time + 1000 *  (long)( jobTime );
    double duration = stopTime - time;



    synchronized (this.target) {
        while (this.target.isWorking) {
            status = 'w';
            showStatus(); // hmmmmmmmm
            try {
                this.target.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        this.target.isWorking = true;
    }

    while (time < stopTime && !killFlag) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        if (goFlag) {
            status = 'p';
            showStatus();
            time += 100;
            this.showProgress.setValue((int)(((time - startTime) / duration) * 100));
        } else {
            status = 'r';
            showStatus();
        }
    }//End While loop here

        showProgress.setValue(100);
        status = 'c';
        showStatus();
        synchronized (target) {
            target.isWorking = false;
            target.notifyAll();

    }
}
```

At first I thought it was `target.notifyAll()` because it is throwing an `IllegalMonitorStateException`, but when I comment it out the thread will objects will construct but when I view them in the GUI 80% of them are displayed as complete without any interation from me and the other 20% are stating that the creature is busy.

At first I thought this was because I pop the kill flag too early but when I moved it lower or removed it the symptoms still persist. I'm deployed at the moment and there are no programmers here haha, any advice you could provide would mean the world.

For the sake of making sure I provide enough information below are the methods I use for interacting with the threads. The below methods work with a button that changes based on whether or not the thread is running.

```
public void showStatus() { //switch that changes status of button used to start / pause / display status of thread
    switch (this.status) {
        case 'r' :
            startJob.setEnabled(true);
            startJob.setText ("Run");
            break;
        case 'p' :
            startJob.setEnabled(true);
            startJob.setText("Pause");
            break;
        case 'w' :
            startJob.setEnabled(false);
            startJob.setText("Working");
            break;
        case 'c' :
            startJob.setEnabled(false);
            startJob.setText("Job Complete");
            break;
    }
}

private class theHandler implements ActionListener {//Listener for Button mentioned above
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == startJob) {
            if (goFlag) {
                goFlag = false;
            } else {
                goFlag = true;
                killFlag = false;
            }
        } else if (event.getSource() == stopJob) {
            if (killFlag) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                killFlag = true;
                status = 'r';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is killing me, I've been digging around to solve this for 6 hours.

**Edit**

After adjusting my code based on MadProgrammer's comment the "target.notifyAll()" is fixed. Now the issue seems to be that all threads appear on the display as complete even though the buttons flash randomly between states for a fraction of a second.

**Edit**

**A lot of edits included below in response to comments**

Below is how I define the job class where killFlag, goFlag, etc. are defined.

```
  class Job extends Item implements SearchableByName, Runnable {
int                                         index;
String                                      name;
int                                         creature;
double                                      jobTime;
Creature                                    target;
boolean                                     goFlag = false;
boolean                                     killFlag = false;
char                                        status;
JButton                                     startJob;
JButton                                     stopJob;
JProgressBar                                showProgress;
JPanel                                      p1;
```

Below is where Creature (target) is defined where boolean isWorking resides:

```
 class Creature extends Entity implements SearchableByName, SearchableByType, Runnable {
int                                     party;
int                                     empathy;
int                                     fear;
int                                     carryCapacity;
Float                                   age;
Float                                   height;
Float                                   weight;
boolean                                 isWorking = false;
```

And in response to the comments here is a picture of how I am displaying the threads:
[image]

Comment: New code should use the higher level concurrency abstractions.  You ought to define your project in terms of Tasks and Executors, rather than threads.  It is particularly difficult to use wait, notify, and notifyAll correctly.  The way you discuss the way in which you want your threads coordinated, you probably ought to be using CountDownLatch as well.  Your homegrown semaphore flags at the very least ought to be declared volatile, since you are not guaranteeing that the updates you make to them will be visible to other threads.

Comment: While there's an indication of GUI, there's no identification of the framework.  If you're using swing, I strongly recommend that you take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) as you violating the single thread rules ;)

Comment: target.notifyAll should be done from within a synchronized block, as notifyAll requires the monitor lock to work

Comment: @MadProgrammer that definently fixed a lot but now all threads spawn complete. the threads do seem to see like they are changing states because the status button changes states randomly for a fraction of a second

Comment: +1 to scottb and MadProgrammer: Java 5 is long since been EOL'd and it introduced higher level concurrency abstractions many many years ago. And Swing is notoriously difficult to use with threads. If you need a more advanced GUI I would go with Eclipse RCP since it is more thread-friendly and honestly is 10x more advanced.

Comment: @John Gaughan I would love to use something other than swing but my Proffessor strictly outlines what we are allowed to use to accomplish our projects. While I appreciate the direction he's given us by doing so, I wish we had a bit more freedom. I spent 2 weeks wishing I could just use a HashMap in this course.

Comment: If this is homework, then please say it is homework and state the parameters of the assignment in your question. I am not trying to be rude or anything, I am just letting you know that you will receive better feedback on this site if you are up front about that. Also, thank you for putting in an honest effort instead of saying "it doesn't work, please do my assignment for me."

Comment: It's a shame when teachers are lazy and don't want to update their curriculum.  That shouldn't fly when you're teaching computer science.

Comment: I agree, I am working on an M.S. in C.S. right now and some of the professors are VERY old-school and refuse to acknowledge that the career field has progressed in the past 40 years. I have had to print out source code for some of them. Those guys need to retire.

Comment: I think it's worth having students do one assignment with the lower-level primitives so they understand why they should use the higher-level ones on real programs.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the creature / job / etc.?  The place where `killFlag`, `goFlag`, `target`, `isWorking`, etc. are defined?  Without that it's a bit hard to see the entire picture.

Comment: @MattMcHenry Absolutely I'm on it right now

Comment: What do you mean by "displaying your threads" exactly?

Comment: Also, please, unify your code; for instance, remove unnecessary `this` qualifiers, I suspect there are quite a lot here.

Comment: Can you "outsmart" your teacher and use an `ExecutorService`? That would greatly simplify your work...

Comment: I ended the While loop before the statements that complete the job. Now the JProgressBar works but the buttons are not performing as they should. The Button that changes its display only shifts between "working" and "pause". Pause will run and pause the thread. waiting should not show up until I am running a thread, and cancel thread just completes the thread?

Comment: @MattMcHenry Fixed the miss labeled run / pause issue and figured out the waiting issue. Only problem left is getting the thread to reset back to 0% progression after hitting the cancel button and being able to restart it with run.

I apologize for the rapid edits but the comments have helped point out a lot of issues that I would rather let everyone know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since some code is still missing, I'm going to enumerate some assumptions first; if any don't hold, my answer below may be incorrect.

1. The `run()` method you gave is inside the `Job` class.
2. The "cancel" button you refer to is the `stopJob` `JButton`

If you're intending to reuse the same `Job` instance for the restart after the 1st run-through, then your basic problem is that your `run()` method terminates.  You have a `while` loop that checks for `!killFlag`, but once that loop ends (i.e. once the job is canceled and `killFlag == true`), there is nothing that would cause it to go back to the beginning and await a subsequent `goFlag == true` state to start running again.  (Also, consider whether the `stopJob` clause in your `actionPerformed()` method needs to do something with `goFlag`.)

On the other hand, if you're intending to create a new `Job` instance to represent the restarted job, then you haven't shown any code that would do that.

I'm being a bit vague in my diagnosis above on purpose, to try to help you figure things out on your own -- that's the best way to learn.  :)  If you need more details, I can try to provide them, just LMK in a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really shed some light on what I need to do! I fixed the bulk of the issues surrounding the buttons. I think what I'm going to do is terminate the thread upon hitting the Cancel button and starting the thread with the run button. I'm looking up safe ways to do that now. Thank you so much again I could't thank you enough!